# CSV Data handling - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, csv

I've been asked at work to create a project to open a CSV and then use a set of conditions to change and save the data using Visual Basic.net (2010)

Although I am comfortable creating files in vb and opening them again into vb, I don't know how to declare the fields so I can query them. For example:

```
if field1 = "Yes" and field2 = "Blue" then textbox1.text = "abcd"
```

Then at a later stage I want to export a file which I'm happy doing where it writes lines to create a new CSV which could be `Field1, textbox1.text, Field3` and so on

Also, would I have to declare `line1.field1` and `line2.field1` or could I declare `line2.field1` as `field25` for example or whatever the next sequential number may be?

Thanks

Comment: Just use a CSV library like [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @sloth Your link to Filehelpers gave a 503 error.

Comment: CSVs are typically used for data exchange rather than persistent storage.  the project designer might want to rethink that especially if there are foreign elements involved.

Comment: What's wrong with using the [TextFieldParser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

- How are you going to read from the file?
- If you do [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx)
  what does it return? *A string array.*
- Does a string array have properties like `line1`? *No, but they do have indexers.*
- How do you access an element in a string array? *With a indexer,
  e.g. `array(0)`.*
- Does an string have properties like `field1`? *Nope.*
- Can you use String.Split to split on the commas and separate the fields? *Yes.*
- Could you write a class that has specific properties defined for each field that has a constructor that'd take a string that represents a row and put the value into the correct fields? *Yes.*
- Could the same class know how to convert itself into a single CSV style line? *Yup.*
- Are there other library that could help you do this? *Probably.*

---

All that being said, you can probably get away with doing something simple like this (**warning: *naive* code sample**):

```
Dim fileName = "C:\testFile.csv"
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
Dim output As New List(Of String)

For Each line In lines
    Dim fields = line.Split(","c)

    fields(0) = "000" 'Blank out number
    If fields(3) = "Y" Then 'Change Y to True
        fields(3) = "True"
    End If
    output.Add(String.Join(","c, fields))
Next

File.WriteAllLines(fileName, output)
```

I gave it input that looked like this:

```
123,abc,Y,Y,N
456,def,Y,N,Y
789,ghi,N,Y,Y
012,jkl,N,N,N
```

and it changed the file to this:

```
000,abc,Y,True,N
000,def,Y,N,Y
000,ghi,N,True,Y
000,jkl,N,N,N
```

Utilities for working with CSV will do a better job than this. There are various ways this won't work (doesn't handle any escape sequences, etc.) but this could be sufficient if you're just wanting to do something quick and dirty and don't need to worry about some things. At the very least hopefully it'll give you a better understanding of how you'd go about solving a problem like this.

I'd recommend writing the output to a different file to test.

Comment: Jeff that is brilliant, although one question if I may, how would I get it to add records for example 
        If fields(3) = "Y" Then
        field(5) = "Yes"
        End If

Comment: The code you described there should handle modifying a separate field on the same row. If you want to add a new row entirely, it'd probably be easiest to add a separate `List(Of Sting)` for the new rows and combine it with the original at the end.